# Lubuntu 18.04 Steam not loading properly

Tags: lubuntu, 18.04, games, steam

I just installed Lubuntu 18.04 and the first thing I did was try to install steam. I tried from the Lubuntu software center and then using "sudo apt install steam." Both gave me the same result. Steam would go through its expected updates and then I was able to login to my account. It would then tell me it was connecting my steam account and updating user configuration. That window then closes but the steam client doesn't pop up. It shows up in the taskbar for about a second before what seems to me like it crashes. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You can find out more details about what went wrong by running `steam` in a terminal and looking at the output.

Answer (score 0):

try purging steam

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
sudo apt-get purge steam
```

then remove files

```
rm $HOME/.steam* (i think .steampid is the folder you want to delete here)
```

then reinstall steam.